# How to select a item from a array and have the next item that is selected be the next item in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, setinterval

I am pretty new to stack overflow and this is my first question here. Sorry if it wasn't clear!

I want to make it so that a item is picked from a array and the next item is the item after it
I also want to pick a item every 15 seconds

I am lost in how to do this so if someone could help me it would be nice :D

(my application is a Discord Bot in node.js)

```js
let options = ["This will be picked first", "This will be picked second", "This will be picked third"]
// the options

    setInterval(function(){
      let final = // I need help here

        // do things

  }, 15000) // every 15 seconds
```

What I want this code to do, is first pick the first option and then 15 seconds later, pick the second option and then pick the third option and repeat

Comment: the easiest solution could be to keep track of the index in a variable outside of the function's scope. declare `let i = 0` in global scope and increment the `i` inside your callback passed into `setInterval`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way is to have a counter variable to keep track of the items in the array you want to pick next, then you can increment the counter
the `%` operator here is used to reset counter back to beginning

```
let options = ["This will be picked first", "This will be picked second", "This will be picked third"];
let counter = 0;

setInterval(function() {
  let final = options[counter % options.length];
  console.log(final);

  counter++;
}, 15000);
```